# Will upgrading an SSD that is almost full help a RAM shortage via the paging file?

Tags: memory, ssd, upgrade, pagefile

On my Win10 machine I have a 1TB SSD that's almost full and my 16GB of RAM has also become insufficient, with memory-intensive applications taking RAM usage up to almost 100% with everything becoming unusably slow.
I can't upgrade RAM (soldered in) but can upgrade to a larger SSD.
Would this help the RAM problem by allowing a larger paging file?

Comment: Missing: How much is your RAM, what virtual machine product are you using, what OS is installed in the VM and how much RAM is the VM allocated. Please Edit your post and add these details.

Comment: Have you tested the speed of your SSD? I posit that as its full its slowing down  causing swap to slow as well.

Answer (score 0):

> On my Win10 machine I have an SSD that's almost full and also have a
> RAM problem, in that using a VM takes RAM usage up to 100% and
> everything becomes unusably slow. I can't upgrade RAM (soldered in)
> but can upgrade the SSD.

No, a larger SSD will not alleviate a memory problem by very much, if at all. If the SSD is so full that it is limiting the paging file, then more likely to help.

You already have an SSD so to the extent memory is paging then you already have that benefit.

Since your memory is not expandable, then your system is what it is until you get a larger system (more memory) which is what VMs need.

I am using a Windows 10 machine with 3 machines running on 16 GB of memory and fast SSD drive.

**Follow up from your edits:**

16 GB is enough for Host (4 GB) and one large or a couple on normal machines (another 8 GB).

Temporary solution:  Move a several very large files temporarily to an External USB Drive to give yourself at least 25% free space.

Make sure TRIM is scheduled to run (Admin Tools, Optimize Drive).

Make sure your VMs have not been allocated too many CPUs (1 with 2 cores is usually enough). Make sure a reasonable of memory has been allocated (Host with 4 or 5 GB, Guest with 4 GB).

Restart and test overall function again. My own system specs are similar to yours and all is very fast.

If you need more space to maintain 25% free, a bigger SSD would be in order.

Comment: Both answers were most helpful. Simply reducing the resources allocated to the VM made such a big difference that the problem is solved. Reputation not high enough to upvote, but appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

16GB of RAM should be sufficient for a VM. Most OS will work happily
in the VM with 4 GB of allocated RAM, which will leave Windows with
12 GB memory which is entirely sufficient.

You have either allocated the VM much too much memory, or some
installed product is using up a lot of your memory.

For the later case, use Task Manager, Details tab, right-click on any
header and click on "Select columns". Check "Working set (memory)"
and click OK. Click the new header twice to sort it by descending
order.
Now you can find if any process is using too much memory.
Look also in the Performance tab, Memory section, for abnormalities.

Comment: Yes indeed.  OP is probably running "too much crap" in the background. :)  You advice is (always) sage but I myself would start them with the startup tasks and not memory as a whole.